# Example error exploring this

Tags: javascript, this

I am working on understanding how `this` works in javascript and came across this example in a tutorial.  This example generates a syntax error for me so I am hoping someone can explain the  the cause of the error.
Code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
        <body>
            <script>
                var myObject = {
                   myProperty:'Icanseethelight',
                   myMethod:function() {
                       var that=this; 
                       var helperFunctionfunction(){
                            function() { 
                                console.log(that.myProperty);
                                console.log(this);
                            }();
                    }
                }

                myObject.myMethod(); // invoke myMethod

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myObject = {
    myProperty:'Icanseethelight',
    myMethod:function() {
       var that=this; 
       var helperFunction = function(){
           console.log(that.myProperty);
           console.log(this);
       }
    }
}
myObject.myMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should replace var `helperFunctionfunction(){`
with `var helperFunction = function(){`